# Handling broadcast receiver issues in Mi & onePlus 3 phones?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Broadcast receiver not working in MI & onePlus 3 phones. I am aware that if you enable auto start then app will start work, but is this a best practice?

what is the best practices to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on devices like MI its better to ask the use to enable Autostart. (May be show a help screen in the beginning). Though there was this project i had worked on and the client insisted this to work without user explicitly enabling auto start. We had to implement a notificationlistener based work around. (Actually apart from broadcast received phones like MI won't support job scheduler, alarmmamnager etc)